# SQL Server Update trigger not updating columns when value is null

Tags: triggers, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014

I have an update trigger that adds +1 to a number column (col1) of rows when another column (col2) was updated to 2 (from another value). I'm trying to count the number of times col2 was updated to 2. The trigger works fine when col1 is not null but I would like to be able to handle the null case as well (treating null as 0).

I figured the coalesce function (`coalesce(deleted.col1+1,1)`) would work but the column remains null if it started out as null. It does "work" with the coalesce function if the value is not null.

The `NOT NULL` condition doesn't work for the null case either. Additionally, a second UPDATE (`SET col1=1`) with a WHERE clause that asks if `deleted.col1 IS NULL` doesn't update in the null case so I'm a little perplexed.

Any ideas as to what the issue is?

Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER schema1.trigger1 
ON schema1.table1 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(col2)
    BEGIN   
        UPDATE t 
        SET t.col1 = coalesce(d.col1+1,1)
        FROM schema1.table1 AS t
        INNER JOIN INSERTED AS i ON t.ID = i.ID
        INNER JOIN DELETED AS d ON i.ID = d.ID
        WHERE i.col2 = 2
          AND d.col2 != 2 
          AND i.col1 = d.col1;
       --WHERE...i.col1 = d.col1 added in case this column is being updated by user
END;
```

First time post so if there's anything I can do to improve my question don't hesitate to let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the `WHERE` clause, not your `COALESCE()` function:

```
WHERE i.col2 = 2 AND d.col2 != 2 AND i.col1 = d.col1;
```

The second condition there (`i.col1 = d.col1`) will never evaluate to TRUE if d.col1 IS NULL.

One possible solution would be to write something like the following:

```
WHERE 
    i.col2 = 2 AND 
    d.col2 != 2 AND 
    (i.col1 = d.col1 OR (i.col1 IS NOT NULL AND d.col1 IS NULL)) ;
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I didn't know NULL=NULL is false.

I actually would want both i.col1 and d.col1 to be NULL if either is NULL, though, since I only want col1 to update if it wasn't part of the update that caused the trigger.

Comment: There's an excellent article called ["How to Get NULLs Horribly Wrong in SQL Server"](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/) by Robert Sheldon that does a good job of explaining some of the peculiarities and "gotchas" of NULL handling - it's well worth a read if you have the time.